# UWP Tooltip with CornerRadius showing white background?

Tags: uwp-xaml

Wondering how I can, ideally through XAML (not C# code), get rid of the white corner edges as seen in the attached image. The Tooltip corners initially appear correctly (no white corner) until the fade-in is complete, then the white corners appear.

[image]

Here is the XAML being used to achieve the CornerRadius. Overridden colours are omitted for brevity.

```
<Style TargetType="ToolTip">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="26" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="LayoutRoot"
                    CornerRadius="5" >
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="OpenStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Closed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="LayoutRoot" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Opened">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="LayoutRoot" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </ContentPresenter>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Thanks!
David

Comment: I have tried your code. but I did not reproduce your issue, have you tried set the `Background` as Transparent in the ToolTip Style?

Comment: Setting  Background to Transparent for either or both of the following does not resolve the problem (NB: XAML reduced only to the relevant properties):
<Style TargetType="ToolTip">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="LayoutRoot"
                        BorderThickness="2"
                        Background="Transparent"
...

Comment: Could you share a code sample for us, I will troubleshot it base on your project.